# Why I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException in a RemoteViewsFactory?

Tags: java, listview, android-appwidget, android-remoteview

I create an appwidget with a listview.
In **RemoteViewsFactory** class I'm populate list from SQLite database. All is fine, but if I put a one string in *updateWidget*() method than I get **IndexOutOfBoundsException** in a *getViewAt* method of **RemoteViewsFactory**.

It's has no logic why it cause Exception. Because in *updateWidget*() method I only set text to one remoteview.

Here a code list and string that cause a problem:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId)
{
    SharedPreferences sPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("WidgetSettings_"+appWidgetId,0);
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial_layout);
    DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);

    // To avoid Exception in a RemoteViewsFactory.getViewAt() method just comment or delete this line
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewListTotal, "Total sum of items"); // this line cause an Exception. If I commenting it then all is OK


    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetRemoteViewsService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.items_list, intent);

    rv.setEmptyView(R.id.items_list, R.id.empty_view);

    final Intent actionIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    actionIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_MANAGE);
    actionIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    actionIntent.setData(Uri.parse(actionIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.items_list, actionPendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.items_list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I done this with a known solution. In a *getViewAt* method I paste a check statement like this:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_item);

    try {
        if(ListItems.size() > 0) //<------- avoid indexoutofbound exception
        {
           // doing something with a remoteviews 
        }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what a bug is it. If someone knows, please post your solution